# Matching a particular enumeration style

Tags: enumerate, two-column, layout

My colleagues and I are working on updating our old textbooks (written with some outdated proprietary software) to LaTeX. However we are rather fond of the layout and enumeration style that we had previously.

In particular, we are interested in keeping the two-column layout for problem sets, and the oversized numbers when enumerating. Who might we go about matching this style with LaTeX? Thanks in advance. (examples shown below)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do what you want with [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). Here's an example with the oversized numbers in two-column format.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problems]{
    label=\raisebox{-4pt}{\huge\color{gray}\arabic*},
    before=\begin{multicols}{2},
    after=\end{multicols}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{problems}
    \item A first problem with a text long enough to span more than a single line
    \item A second problem
    \item A third problem
    \item A fourth problem
\end{problems}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with more lines in the item text?

Comment: @egreg yes, and it seemed to work well. I modified the example to show the result. Did I miss something else?

Comment: I'm assuming the lettered version of enumerate works correctly inside of each numbered problem?

Comment: Also, how would you make large headers that break up sections, but the enumeration is kept consistent across all sections?

Comment: @Patch Of course, you can still use the `enumerate` environment, so you can have a lettered version if you want. The formatting in the example is just that of this `problems` environment I defined. For your second question, do you mean that you want the problem numbers to continue across different sections? If so, you can add the key `resume` in the argument of `\setlist`.

Comment: @Vincent I just realized that when I use a \ref command to reference an enumerated item with this special formatting that the reference instance also includes the fancy formatting -- which of course looks super weird inside of a paragraph. What would I add to the preamble to remove the formatting and make \ref look standard?

Comment: @Patch You can modify the reference style in `\setlist` without modifying the label, with the `ref` keyword. For example, if you add the line `ref=\arabic*` in `\setlist`, the labels will just be referenced as arabic numbers without any formatting. There are more details on page 5 of `enumitem`'s [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).